# WPF Access window created on different UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I created new Window on a different thread because it has heavy UI operations, that was done to keep my main window run smoothly. Everything works perfectly. 
But here is the question:
**How I can access newly created window?**
After calling `Dispatcher.Run()` I can not manipulate `visualisationWindow` anymore. I want to keep access to that newly created window object.
Here is how my window created:

```
    private void CreateVisualisationWindow()
    {
        Thread VisualisationWIndowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
        VisualisationWIndowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        VisualisationWIndowThread.IsBackground = true;
        VisualisationWIndowThread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadStartingPoint()
    {
        Visualisation visualisationWindow = new Visualisation();
        visualisationWindow.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

Also I tried accessing it through `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(VisualisationWIndowThread)` but seems I misunderstand some core things.

Comment: Using multiple ui threads is one of those things you can do technically BUT is almost always a bad idea. I think a different approach with one ui thread is probably a better plan. What does your visualisation window actually do? As an alternative, why do you need to access the actual window? I would expect to work with some sort of UI agnostic viewmodel which CAN deal with multiple threads.

Comment: @Andy, there are multiple ui threads only because second window includes WinForms element that using UI thread heavily (screenBG.Render() where screenBG is of BufferedGraphics type - that mehtod can only be executed on UI thread) and there is no way to avoid it even with async approach. It is used to display some science data

Comment: I'm not familiar with screenbg.render. Do you have to use that? I was thinking maybe writeablebitmap. Process on a backround thread, translate to bitmap, freeze and pass back. Although.... Just building a wbm is very fast so long as you free up the ui thread a little between changes you can construct very quickly changing images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simulated your issue using two WPF Window objects and a timer to ensure that the Second Window was created before calling operations on it. Below is my code sample and it updates the second Windows TextBox every five seconds:

```
    private Timer _timer;
    private SecondWindow _secondWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateVisualisationWindow();
        _timer = new Timer(Callback);
        _timer.Change(5000, 5000);
    }

    private void Callback(object state)
    {
        UpdateSecondWindowText();
    }

    private void CreateVisualisationWindow()
    {
        Thread VisualisationWIndowThread = new Thread(ThreadStartingPoint);
        VisualisationWIndowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        VisualisationWIndowThread.IsBackground = true;
        VisualisationWIndowThread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadStartingPoint()
    {
        _secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
        _secondWindow.SecondWindowTextBlock.Text = "Hello";
        _secondWindow.Show();
         Dispatcher.Run();
    }

    private void UpdateSecondWindowText()
    {
        _secondWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            _secondWindow.SecondWindowTextBlock.Text = _secondWindow.SecondWindowTextBlock.Text + " World";
        }));
    }
```

So the trick is, you need to call the Dispatcher on the second Window in order to gain access to it.